# Can a function that was passed as a component property be called in a test using react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

What I want is:

1. Find the way to call the component's function;
2. Test the value after function execution.

For example, the behavior is:

1. A user types something into an input;
2. After each typing, a function is fired and updates the value and passes this value into another component.

I have to write a test that the passed value to not exceeds the max length. In this case, updated value will represent a property from the local state that is passed to another component after its update.
So, how can I call this function and verify that the max length is not greater then I expect?

Comment: It's not clear to me how those components fit together. If an action *only* changes the internal state of a component, it's not testable - that internal state is an implementation detail. So think about the observable side effects of that state change - does the DOM change, for example? That said, it looks like you're passing a function in, so maybe make that a *test double* so you can assert that it was correctly called?

Comment: When a click occurs for this input it fires a function that is declared in the container and do some logic (update a state property), then I pass this updated state property in AComponent props. What I wanted to do is to test what exactly I pass into AComponent when this click event happens.

Comment: You're currently testing `A`, **not** the container. You could *mock* `A`, and ensure it gets the correct prop, but it's unclear from your description what testable external effect this internal communication would have.

Comment: jonrsharpe I've created a sample https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-architecture-ulz4f

Comment: Put a [mcve] *in the question*.

Comment: Maybe I have to mock setState function in my tests?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it. Again, internal state is an implementation detail. And I said *in the question*, why have you edited *out* more information?

Comment: Stop editing information *out* of the question. Either put a proper [mcve] *in the actual question* (links to off-site examples must be supplementary **only**), or just delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I've created [a sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/tests-hi7um) where I show how to manage to fire a function and control the value I pass after function execution.

A brief description is:

1. Mock nested component
2. return a jsx with indicating parameters as a function params for the mocked component
3. simulate an event for mocked component (function attached to the event will be fired and local state will be updated)
4. use getByTestId to get an element that contains updated data
5. Verify if data is what is expected to be.